# Error code not caught in shell script

Tags: unix, ssh, kerberos

I'm facing an issue where an error in the shell script I have is not getting caught. The code snippet below:

```
ssh -n -q ${REMOTE_SERVER} "kinit -kt /etc/keytabs/authenticate1.keytab user1@email.com"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    error="Can't kinit on SSH server"
fi
```

The full function is:

```
func_kinit_check() {
    ssh -n -q ${REMOTE_SERVER} "kdestroy"
    ssh -n -q ${REMOTE_SERVER} "kinit -kt /etc/keytabs/${USR}.keytab ${USR}@EMAIL.COM"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        errorMessage="Can't kinit on SSH server"
    fi
}
```

The script runs perfectly but, if the above snippet fails, the error isn't caught by the error catching statement below. There are couple of more such `ssh` statements in the same script doing other tasks (`ls`, `rm`, etc). They work properly and do return the error code in case of failure.

I've no idea whether it's `kinit` that's problematic or something else that I'm missing in my code. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the script if its not too long?

Comment: It is too long actually. But it's fairly simple structured if I wish to explain here.
The code snippet above is inside a function & the script contains 12 other such functions (ssh'ing to remote server & executing rm,ls,other such unix ops).

Then there's a main menu driven code snippet that calls these functions one by one.

Comment: I think what's happening is you're seeing the SSH result, and not the condition result from the kinit execution statement.

Comment: Added the full function, like I said it's just that code snippet only; nothing more.

I thought the same that I might be seeing the SSH result but if it is, then the other functions SSH'ing and performing various unix functions (ls, rm) should also behave in similar fashion. However, they are giving the proper result (be it error message or a successful execution).